# Make Calls with iPhone in background Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I'm developing an app that is going to be meant for emergency/medical purposes. A core feature of it is that it will be capable of making an emergency call in the background if it detects something. This call needs to be able to occur when the phone is locked and the app isn't necessarily active.

Is there anyway to accomplish this? I know that apps can have their own background activity, but is there a way for them to make a call in the background.

If not, is there another service of API that I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: No, you cannot do this (as far as I'm aware). You can still send networking messages in the background, so if an event is triggered you would need it to send a message to your backend that would tell your own service to make the call for them.